# isometrically isomorphism

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

How can embed separable Banach to Cb(X)(family of all bounded continuous functions on topological space X) with non metrizable X ?
If X is locally compact or Tychonof  is very well.

note : We know that there exists an isometrically isomorphic between any Banach H and H^ (H^ is second dual of H or H^=H**) and know by Kuratofski theorem we can make an isometrically isomorphic between H and Cb(H).

But we want a topological space X that is not metrizable because i want Cech-stone extension an Cech-stone compactification is not metrizable in general?

Comment: I don't understand why you insist on  $X$ being non metrizable. Suppose you embedded into $C(Y)$  with metrizable $Y$; then let $X$ be the disjoint union of $Y$ with some non-metrizable topological space. It's never difficult to destroy a good property.

Comment: @Fundamental, for example? you can't destroy the property of vector space being zero-dimensional (I think it is a nice property) without destroying that space :)

Comment: thank you for your notice .Because cech-stone compactification of a metrizable space is not metrizable in general.I would like to have a completely regular space and define Cb(X).